# XCode Build Failed Doesn't Show Errors

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I am trying to build my app.  I run it (which until recently worked fine), now it won't work and it gives me no errors and nothing in console.  Any ideas how I can find the issue?

Edit:
What happened is my product name started with a number and it auto-filled my bundle as com.domain.-mwg 
Instead of the number it had a hyphen. So, I got in info.plist and on bundle identifier I changed it to com.domain.5mwg
It was after this it messed up. I tried changing the plist back but it still messes up.

Comment: You didn't happen to take a snapshot pretty recently did you?

Comment: More information other than 'won't work' might help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Enable "Exception Breakpoints."

1. On the left side of Xcode, select the "Breakpoint Navigator."
2. On the bottom of this pane, click the "+" button and select "Add Exception Breakpoint."

Have the rest of the settings look like this:

[image: Exception Breakpoints]

Comment: This answer should come by default on over half the questions here on SO.

Comment: Note: sometimes after adding exception breakpoints, you don't receive any explanation of the exception until you press the "play" (continue program execution) button a few times after the crash. This "play" button is located in the debug area above the console.

Comment: Away from computer now but will try when I get back. I edited original question with more info that may be helpful.

Comment: It didn't help any.  I click the Run button and it just shows Build Failed

Comment: @user717452 - Do you see anything specified in the "Issue Navigator" or the "Log Navigator" panes (left side)?

Comment: No.  Nothing other than a couple normal things that already existed...deprecated values and such, but they were all there before when the app would build.